# Different between private node handler and not private

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using ROS melodic and Gazebo 9.9.0 on an Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.

I've been reading this: http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/NodeHandles, but I don't understand what is (or are) the different between this two declarations:

```
ros::NodeHandle n;
```

And

```
ros::NodeHandle n("~");
```

What are the different between a private and a not private node handler?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328889/different-between-private-node-handler-and-not-private/) by [Elric](https://answers.ros.org/users/30817/elric/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2019-07-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The first will look for your parameter in the global namespace (ei it will find /my_param) the second will look under the nested namespaces of the node itself (ei it will find /namespace/my_node_name/my_param).

You can still find the local namespace copy of that parameter with the global nodehandle, but you will need to type in alot more information.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2019-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4